# position banner at the top as the top layer

Tags: css

here's the link to the page:
http://whiterootmedia.com/test/test3

here's the code:

```
    <div id="banner" style="position:absolute; top:0px; width:100%; background:url('../../images/banner_repeat.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; <!-- border:solid pink 1px; -->"> 
    <ul id="banner_ul">
    <li id="wrm"><a href="http://whiterootmedia.com"><i>The homepage of White Root Media!</i></a></li>
    <li id="google"><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/115943543157099352927/115943543157099352927" target="_blank"><i>+1 us on Google!</i></a></li>
    <li id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/White-Root-Media/194381903928501" target="_blank"><i>Like us on Facebook!</i></a></li>
    <li id="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/WhiteRootMedia" target="_blank"><i>Tweet about us on Twitter!</i></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="container" style="<!-- border:solid yellow 1px -->; display: table;">

    <div id="content" style="<!-- border:solid purple 1px; --> display:table-cell; ">
    This content determines the height. The text will not wrap. There will be a min-width yet to be determined.
    This content determines the height. The text will not wrap. There will be a min-width yet to be determined.
    This content determines the height. The text will not wrap. There will be a min-width yet to be determined.

    </div>

    <div id="right_column" style="display: table-cell; <!-- border:solid orange 1px; --> height:100%; width:270px; background-image:url('../../images/treetrunk7.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;">tree</div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="position:relative; top:-1px; background-image:url('../../images/grass.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100%; height:100px;">grass</div>
```

I would like the banner to sit at the top layer while the "container" div to sit underneath

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wyvk8/

I removed your inline CSS styles and applied them via CSS rules as follows:

```
html, body {
    height     : 100%;
    min-height : 100%;
}
#banner {
    position      : absolute;
    top           : 0;
    left          : 0;
    height        : 100px;
    width         : 100%;
    overflow      : hidden;
    background    : url('../../images/banner_repeat.jpg') repeat-x;
    z-index       : 2;
}
#content {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 100px;
    left     : 0;
    right    : 270px;
    bottom   : 100px;
    overflow : auto;
}
#right_column {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    bottom     : 0;
    right      : 0;
    width      : 270px;
    z-index    : 3;
    background : url('../../images/treetrunk7.png') repeat-y;
}
#footer {
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 0;
    bottom     : 0;
    right      : 270px;
    height     : 100px;
    overflow   : hidden;
    background : url('../../images/grass.png') repeat-x;
    z-index    : 2;
}
```

And I changed how your HTML is nested to be like this:

```
<div id="banner"> 
    <ul id="banner_ul">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
    
<div id="content">
    ....
</div>
    
<div id="right_column">tree</div>

<div id="footer">grass</div>
```

The effect of the above code is that the `#header` element is positioned at the top, the `#content` element is on the left and centered vertically, the `#footer` element is positioned at the bottom, and the `#right_column` element is positioned on the right side of the page. The `#content` element gets scroll-bar when it's content overflows and the scroll-bar is applied directly to the element.

### BONUS ROUND

You can hide the right column when the page is too narrow using CSS media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    #right_column {
        display : none;
    }
    #content, #banner, #footer {
        right : 0;
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wyvk8/1/ (if you make the page less than 500px wide the right column will disappear, only in browsers that support media queries)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `position: fixed` to your top banner, I presume element id "banner_ul". This means it will sit outside the page layout like an absolute positioning, however it is unaffected by scrolling; it will always sit `top: 0; left: 0;` in relation to the browser window. Remember to appropriately adjust all containers below this so they sit [the banner's height] from the top of the window, otherwise they will overlap with the banner when the page loads.

Comment: I don't want to use fix though?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking then... I already see the banner above the main text. What do you mean by making it a layer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have wrapped your banner div arround all the elements and therefor it wont be layered on top of the container div because it affects that div too since its inside of the banner div.